# Having permissions issues with procmail and python script

Tags: python, procmail

So here is my procmalirc.
The script seems to run as the "user" of the mailbox so the script CANT create locks or flush or remove messages because the procmail seems to have a lock on the mailbox.

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
LOGFILE = $HOME/pm.log
LOGABSTRACT = "All"
VERBOSE = "on"


:0
* ^From: .*address.*
* ^Subject:.*su to root.*
{
:0c:
/var/spool/mail/tdproxymail

:0ahi
| /usr/local/tdproxy/MAILSCRIPTS/script.py
}
```

I'm delivering the mail to the inbox and sending it to the script. When I rrun the python script I loop through the mailbox...looking for the correct email...

```
mbox = mailbox.mbox('/var/mail/tdproxymail')

for key, msg in mbox.iteritems():
    print(key)
    if "su to root" not in (msg['subject']):
        continue
```

Everything processes fine but when I get to

```
mbox.remove(key)
mbox.flush()
mbox.close()
```

it is saying I don't have permissions on the lock from the procmail I think...

> Subject: su to root   Folder:
>   /usr/local/tdproxy/MAILSCRIPTS/edwards_sudo.py                    812
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/tdproxy/MAILSCRIPTS/script.py", line 94, in 
>       mbox.lock()   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/mailbox.py", line 625, in lock
>       _lock_file(self._file)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/mailbox.py", line 1976, in _lock_file
>       pre_lock = _create_temporary(f.name + '.lock')   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/mailbox.py", line 2025, in _create_temporary
>       os.getpid()))   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/mailbox.py", line 2015, in _create_carefully
>       fd = os.open(path, os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL | os.O_RDWR, 0666) OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/var/mail/tdproxymail.lock.1571858501.tdproxy.91248'

I wanted to try to process the email just sys.stdin
but I tried both:

```
#msg = email.message_from_file(sys.stdin)
#msg = email.parser.Parser().parse(sys.stdin)
```

and it says that is_multipart is false which I know is not the correct case...so in short if I access the mailbox it says there is an attachment but if I  use the stdin of the pipe there supposedly is no attachment

**QUESTION**

How can I process and then delete the email from the mailbox since there seems to be a permissions issue in running the script as the user of the incoming mail.

Answer (score 0):

You have an incorrect filename. `/var/mail/tdproxymail.1571851019.tdproxy.81261` is not a file which exists or which you should have any permission to access. Your mbox filename is `/var/mail/tdproxymail` and individual messages are slices within that file.

(That's how mbox works; other folders have different structures, and in fact `1571851019.tdproxy.81261` looks vaguely like what an individual message file in a maildir folder directory might look like.)

Looping over the entire mailbox looking for the latest message is completely crazy anyway. Accepting the message on standard input is *by far* the more sensible, robust, and efficient approach, so I would instead explore what you can do to fix that (probably something simple; but also probably best posted as a separate question). If you can't solve that, a better quick and dirty - but still pretty desperate - workaround might be to write the message to an individual temporary file, and pass that to Python.

Just to be explicit, the hypothesis that this is related to mailbox locking seems false.  Locking an mbox happens by other means than a lockfile on most architectures (typically `flock` or `fcntl`; but check the output of `procmail -v` to see what's the compiled-in behavior on your system) - precisely because normal users don't have permission to create new files in the directory where their inbox lives.

*Probably* the Python `mailbox` code tries to copy the `mbox` file to a different location because manipulating it in memory is usually not a good idea (though in this particular case it could perhaps work; but again, really, don't do that). I have not tried that code; but a typical arrangement is for library functions to examine whether `os.environ['TMPDIR']` is set and, if so, use that for temporary files.

But in fact, I guess the root cause of your problem is that you added the `h` flag to the recipe which writes to Python. Of course you don't get a multipart message then; you get no body at all, because you told Procmail to only give the headers to your script.

As an aside, the spaces around the equals signs are syntax errors. Procmail, like the shell, requires assignments to be of the form `variable=string` or `variable="quoted string"` with no whitespace on either side of the `=` character.

```
# Fix incorrect assignment syntax, no spaces around =
SHELL=/bin/sh
LOGFILE=$HOME/pm.log
LOGABSTRACT="All"
VERBOSE="on"

# Drop the h flag and then also the copying and the a flag
# Also, trailing wildcard is unnecessary in regexes; Procmail matches on any substring
:0i
* ^From: .*address
* ^Subject:.*su to root
| /usr/local/tdproxy/MAILSCRIPTS/script.py
```

If you desperately want to save the message to a file first, write it to a directory like `/tmp/` and capture the file name from Procmail's `LASTFOLDER` variable. But with the fix to remove the `h` flag, I trust that will be unnecessary.

(You will still of course need to remove the code to attempt to manipulate the `mbox` file from Python and just accept the message on standard input.)

Comment: Or maybe Python code which you are not showing us attempts to create a temporary file with that name, but obviously lacks the permission? That would make sense, as removing an individual message from an mbox file entirely in memory is not usually done, even though it could probably work by simply truncating the original file in this specific limited case. Probably you could tell the temp file function to use a different directory, where you do have write permission.

Comment: so I updated the errror...yoou can see it traces back to the mbox.lock() in the python code...so it can't even write the lock file......

Comment: No, you are attempting to create a file but it's not a lock file, probably exactly as per my speculation in the previous comment.

Comment: It' not clear how `sudo.py` or `milbox.py` are related to `script.py`

Comment: sudo.py? mailbox.py? there is only 1 script.....runs under the users account but not through procmail........ edwards_sudo.py is the only scrpit run... the otherr are error rreporting from the python libraries used.

Comment: The traceback shows `edwards_sudo.py` (sorry missed the prefix) and `mailbox.py`

Comment: I was tryiing to obfuscate some of the script names... script.py is the only script with runs.. on the line mbox.lock() it fails.....due to a permissions issue....

Comment: So I had my sysadmin move the account of the receiving emaili iinto the "mail" grooup. Now I can run the script from the account fine but it will still throw the errror via procmail. Close but not there yet

Comment: Oh, I think I see now where the root cause was. See update just now.

Comment: And maybe ask your sysadmin to switch back; you really do not want to give random user scripts privileges they should not need.